# How to display multiple Texts and Images in an item of RecyclerView or ListView?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, textview, android-recyclerview

I'm using a `RecyclerView` to display a list of data from server. The data contain text and an uncertain number of urls of images with HTML tag. For each item, I'm now using `HTML.fromHTML()` with a ImageGetter to parse the data, get images and display them in a `TextView`.

However, the images in `TextView` cannot interact with user. Events on the images like click, magnifying and save are not supported by `TextView`. And I tried using a `Webview` instead, but its performance is poor.

I also tried to write a compound view which extends a `LinearLayout`, and add `TextViews` and `ImageViews` dynamically (the number of images for each item are not certain), but it behaved strangely in the `RecyclerView`.

Is there any better idea or should I improve my solutions forementioned?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be better if you show some screen or mockup which shows how your `ListView` should look. And using `html` code with image tags in `TextView` is definitely is not a best choice.

Comment: @Foxinsocks I'm displaying a thread of a forum using the `RecyclerView`, each item of which is just like a post or reply in the thread. A post may contains multiple images based on its content. The string I get from server is like "...string... [image1] ...string.....[image2]...string.....", and the urls of [image] tag is obtained from server at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found by myself with the help of other programmers on StackOverFlow. For those who may see this question, please check [Android - Custom dynamically-generated compound View recreated in RecyclerView, causing poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144806/android-custom-dynamically-generated-compound-view-recreated-in-recyclerview).
The idea is simple, creating a `CompoundView` extending `LinearLayout` which adds `TextView`s and `ImageViews` dynamically based on the data attached. Note that the processes of creating views and setting data for the them are seperate. For other details, please check the url above.