# Android - Custom dynamically-generated compound View recreated in RecyclerView, causing poor performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view, android-recyclerview

I'm using a custom `CompoundView` which extends `LinearLayout` to display items of a `RecyclerView`. Each item displays an article which contains multiple paragraphs and images.

The `CompoundView` adds `TextView` or `ImageView` dynamically based on the data attached by `CompoundView.setData(List<DataPiece> pieces)`, the number of which is unknown before data is attached.

Each `DataPiece` object tells `CompoundView` whether it's a piece of text or an image. And here is the code for `CompoundView.setData(List<DataPiece> pieces)`:

```
public void setData(List<DataPiece> pieces) {
    removeAllViews();
    for (DataPiece dataPiece : pieces) {
        switch (dataPiece.getType()) {
            case IMAGE:
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
                ...
                addView(imageView);
                break;
            case TEXT:
                TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                ...
                addView(textView);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `RecyclerView.Adapter.onBindViewHolder()`, the data is attached to `CompoundView` by calling `MyViewHolder.compoundView.setData(...)`. And it works fine when the `RecyclerView` is created.

However, for a `CompoundView` item with multiple `ImageView`s and `TextView`s, when I scroll away from it and then scroll back, the scroll becomes heavily unsmooth.

I guess it's because `removeAllViews()` in `setData()` is called, and the `CompoundView` creation for-loop is executed again by the recycler. But I don't know how to avoid this.

And I also wonder why the scroll is always smooth when using `TextView`(with Images) in a `RecyclerView` even it's recycled too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using your custom/compound `View` merely for the `RecyclerView` list you want to create, you would be much better off creating an XML layout for one list item, and then using `RecyclerView`'s built-in methods to add data to `View`s in your list item.

Comment: @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh Thank you! But the number of `TextView`s and `ImageView` is not certain until data is attached. So I have to add `View`s dynamically in an item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple considerations that could go into deciding what the best approach might be.

First, do you have an idea about the maximum number of items in the recycler's list? If it is just a handful, maybe you could ditch the `RecyclerView` approach and just add your `CompoundView` into a container hosted by a `ScrollView`.

Secondly - is the layout of each item fairly complicated (a.k.a. are there many `TextViews`, `ImageViews` etc. in it)? If yes, maybe you could take an approach that would resemble an `ExpandableListView` - show a summary as each list item and expand to the full layout of the item on click.

Thirdly - if none of the above is acceptable and you still want to go the current approach - don't construct/add your view in the binding method. Do it in the `onCreateViewHolder`, when the system expects you to construct your view (I don't know for sure but by the time you're called on `onBindViewHolder` your view might have been already added to the hierarchy and any hierarchical change to it has a ripple effect on its containers - but don't take my word for it, I don't actually know the view is already added, it is just an assumption). You will have to assign each item a different type, so that in `onCreateViewHolder` you could match the view type with the supporting data (for the addition of the corresponding number of child views); create the view from scratch each time - this way you don't need to call on `removeAllViews`. Something like(I left out parts of the adapter that are not relevant to the case):

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<DataPiecesList> mItems;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<DataPiecesList> items) {
        mItems = items;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CompoundView compoundView = new CompoundView();
        List<DataPiece> dataPieces = mItems.get(viewType);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataPieces.size(); i++)
        {
            // construct TextView or ImageView or whatever
            compoundView.add(child);
        }
        MyViewHolder view = new MyViewHolder(compoundView);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        CompoundView compoundView = viewHolder.itemView;
        DataPiece dataPiece = mItems.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < compoundView.getChildCount(); j++)
        {
            compoundView.getChildAt(j) <- dataPiece.get(j);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The 3rd way works. The idea of replacing ViewType with position and finding existing child by `getChildAt()` are really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView` is supposed to reuse the views. It will be slow if you throw away the already created `TextView` / `ImageView` objects and create new ones every time.

It sounds like you need a `RecyclerView` with multiple view types. The idea is to create multiple view holders - some of them with `ImageView`, the others with `TextView`. You'll have to override the [getItemViewType(int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) method of your adapter - it should return different values for the IMAGE items and the TEXT items. The [onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup,%20int)) receives a viewType parameter so you know which type of ViewHolder to create there. In the [onBindViewHolder(VH holder, int position)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) you could assume that the holder passed to you is the correct type (i.e. the type with `TextView` for TEXT items and the type with `ImageView` for IMAGE items), so there is no need to remove its child views and create them again.

There is nice article about RecyclerView's Adapters with multiple view types [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)).

Comment: Thank you! But I want to display an article-like object in each item, and each article may contains several paragraphs and images. So I think it's difficult to calculate the positions of items with different viewTypes. And the `TextView`s and `ImageView`s should be treated as a single item logically in my case.

Comment: And the hyperlink of 'here' is wrong, could you please modify it? thx :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for noticing the broken link - I fixed it. :)